# wampserver, Localhost and haccess rewrite problem

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

sorry but i m kind newbie working with haccess file.

I have a site working on localhost using Wampserver.

When i access my website, example:
localhost:81/mywebsite/

,i can access the website,
but when i click a button, to go for example to my blog page, instead of localhost:81/mywebsite/myBlog it takes me to localhost:81/myBlog

Can anyone help me how do i do a rewrite rule on haccess file to redefine the url?
Right now my haccess file looks something like:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mywebsite/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
  RewriteRule /mywebsite/index.php [L]
```

Thanks

Windows10
WampServer
Google Chrome

Comment: Well this is controlled by the ahchor tag you create in the main site! Not really a job for an `.htaccess`, or url rewrite

Comment: You could read [This on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

Comment: And why are you using port 81 instead of 80?